# How to import images from JSON data into create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, create-react-app

So I have JSON data that includes the path to the images thats located in my public folder (/public/images). Like so,

```
const data = [
{
    "key": 1,
    "name": "Goal Squad",
    "techs": ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
    "image": "../public/images/test.jpg"
},
{
    "key": 2,
    "name": "WesterosCraft",
    "techs": ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
    "image": "../public/images/test.jpg"
},
```

And based on reading a few other similar situations, this is what I've tried in my component;

```
class Card extends Component  {

render() {
    const { name, description, image } = this.props;
    const items = Object.values(this.props.techs);

    console.log(this.props)

    return (
        <CardWrapper>
            <Row>
                <Column colmd6 colsm12>
                    <Header card>{name}</Header>
                    <TechList>{items.map(tech =>
                        tech
                    ).join(' / ')}</TechList>
                    <Text regular>{description}</Text>
                    <Button>Visit Website</Button>
                </Column>

                <Column colmd6 colsm12>
                    <img src={require(`${image}`)} alt={name}/>
                </Column>
            </Row>
        </CardWrapper>
    )
}
```

But create-react-app throws the error "Error: Cannot find module '../public/images/test.jpg'

Any hints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

we can not use require dynamically.you can change your data like this.

```
const data = [
    {
        "key": 1,
        "name": "Goal Squad",
        "techs": ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
        "image": require("../public/images/test.jpg")
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "name": "WesterosCraft",
        "techs": ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
        "image": require("../public/images/test.jpg")
    }
]
```

Comment: react will not allow images outside src, should be require('src')

Comment: Nice solution, it also works with absolute imports, like `require("@images/test.jpg");`

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it worked for me,

First change the file/format name to `.js` instead of `.json` and edit the code like this.

```html
import React from 'react';
import TestIMG1 from "../public/images/test.jpg";
import TestIMG2 from "../public/images/test.jpg";



export const data = [
{
    key: 1,
    name: "Goal Squad",
    techs: ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
    image: TestIMG1
},
{
    key: 2,
    name: "WesterosCraft",
    techs: ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
    image: TestIMG2
},
```

then import it into a component like this:

```html
    {data.map((item) => {
      return(
      <div>
        <img src={item.image} width=""  height="" alt=""/>
      </div>  
    )
   })}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
module.exports = [
    {
        "key": 1,
        "name": "Goal Squad",
        "techs": ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
        "image": "../public/images/test.jpg"
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "name": "WesterosCraft",
        "techs": ["React & Redux", "Express", "MySQL"],
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et",
        "image": "../public/images/test.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Save your file as .js